# Sonar issue : Classes and methods that rely on the default system encoding should not be used

Tags: java, sonarqube, inputstream

I'm getting an error while checking the code quality of code using sonar. Here is error

```
Classes and methods that rely on the default system encoding should not be used : Remove this use of constructor "InputStreamReader(InputStream)"
```

And here is code

```
private StringBuilder getServerResponse(URLConnection connection) throws IOException {
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        final StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        return response;
    }
```

I'm getting this error on below line :-

```
final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

I've tried to find the solution but didn't get any success.
any pointer would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
 connection.getInputStream(), java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset())
);
```

Try using this. 
More about the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22115303

Comment: `defaultCharset()` is very obviously not different from not specifyinh the charset in the first place.

Comment: TBH It is just a workaround. It tricks findbugs into not reporting the issue. That's why I said "try". Using UTF would be a better solution of course.